# Triggering the error handler for a Promise in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I'm working with $q in Angular, and trying to chain some promises together so that I only perform an action once all my Promises have been successfully resolved. However, if any one of them fails, I want to avoid performing that action. By way of example:

```
function getData() {
    return $http.get('url').then(
        function(goodResponse) {
            //do stuff
        },
        function(badResponse) {
            return $q.reject("getData failed");
        }
}

function firstPromise() {
    return getData().then(
        function() {
            //got the data
        },
        function(error) {
            return $q.reject(new BespokeErrorObject({message: error}));
        }
    );
}

function performAllPromises() {
    // Has access to $q
    $q.all(firstPromise(), ... ).then(
        function() {
            // All my Promises were fulfilled successfully
            console.log("All good");
        },
        function(error) {
            // Any one of them failed. Bail.                                        
            console.log(error.message);
        }
}
```

In my application (which is slightly more involved than this example), I'm getting the `All good` output rather than the contents of the Error that is thrown, which is not what I expect to happen based on my understanding of the documentation. Am I using `all` incorrectly?

*Update*: Updated to use `$q.reject` as suggested by Nikos, and added extra layer as in the real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PEBCAK issue. The offending line is

```
$q.all(firstPromise(), ... ).then(
```

which should be

```
$q.all([firstPromise(), ...]).then(
```

A subtle, but very important difference.

Answer (score 1):

To reject a promise from any `then` callback, you have to `return $q.reject(xxx)`.

In your case:

```
function getData() {
    return $http.get('url').then(
        function(goodResponse) {
            //do stuff
        },
        function(badResponse) {
            return $q.reject("getData failed");
        }
}
```

Comment: It's still refusing to work. The $http promise is actually wrapped in another Promise, but I've updated the $http one to use $q.reject and that propagates to the correct error handler. I then call $q.reject from it in the hope that the error handler for `all` will be called, but it goes into the success handler. However, experimenting with another promise in `all` shows that rejecting one does call the error handler. There's an unreturned promise somewhere.

Comment: Not the root of the problem, but this is very helpful. Thanks!